# Dynamic checkboxes based on drop down select in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to hide checkbox based on the select value in Jquery. For an example, if the user selects 1 it hides checkbox 1 so on.

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<label for="dropdown">Dropdown:</label></th><td><select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>

</select>
<div id='checkbox'>
<label for="id_checkbox_0"><input id="id_checkbox_0" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 1</label>
<label for="id_checkbox_1"><input id="id_checkbox_1" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" /> 2</label>
<label for="id_checkbox_2"><input id="id_checkbox_2" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" /> 3</label>
<label for="id_checkbox_3"><input id="id_checkbox_3" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" /> 4</label>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {  
    $('#checkbox').hide();
    $("#dropdown").change(function() {
        $('#checkbox').show();
        var index = $(':selected', this).index();
        $('input:(#id_checkbox_'+index+')').hide(); 
        $('input:not(#id_checkbox_'+index+')').show();

     });

 });
```

**JSFiddle Link:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ffs408u6/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I propose is you put each `label`/`checkbox` inside a `div` that has a data attribute corresponding to the value of the `select`:

```
<div data-id="1">
  <label for="id_checkbox_0">
    <input id="id_checkbox_0" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 1
  </label>
</div>
```

Then make your jQuery look like this:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
    var index = $(this).val();
    $("[data-id]").show();
    $("[data-id=" + index + "]").hide();
    $('#checkbox').show();
 });
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ffs408u6/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, though you've already accepted an answer:

```
var checkboxes = $(’input[type="checkbox"]').hide();
$('#dropdown').on('change', function(){
    var select = this;
    checkboxes.show().filter(function() {
        return this.value !== select.value;
    }).hide();
});
```

If you want to instead hide the parent, label, elements (including the child inputs):

```
var checkboxes = $(’input[type="checkbox"]').hide();
$('#dropdown').on('change', function(){
    var select = this;
    checkboxes.show().filter(function() {
        return this.value !== select.value;
    }).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: you meant $('input[type="checkbox"]').hide();? Its not working for me :(.